# Logstash grok pattern for Dropwizard request logs

Tags: logstash, dropwizard, grok

I am using 0.6.2 version of dropwizard and I wanted to publish all request logs on Logstash and do some analysis on it.
LogStash has a grok pattern of apache logs. [COMBINEDAPACHELOG](https://github.com/elasticsearch/logstash/blob/f8e00994fe5a57bff5b138b2a97a80c4d8c1a6e6/patterns/grok-patterns)

But when I use that I get a grok parse failure.Does any one know what is the grok pattern of Dropwizard request logs ?

These are some of my request logs

```
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Aug/2014:18:38:43 +0000] "GET /v1/stores?quality_filter=true&page_number=0&radius=50&lng=-81.21630272972303&items_per_page=100&lat=41.16857743673455 HTTP/1.1" 200 87 39 39
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Aug/2014:18:38:43 +0000] "GET /v1/stores?quality_filter=true&page_number=0&radius=50&lng=-83.2059536279733&items_per_page=100&lat=42.23786990368085 HTTP/1.1" 200 87 142 142
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Aug/2014:18:38:43 +0000] "GET /v1/stores?page_number=0&radius=50&lng=-4.211522201080072&items_per_page=100&lat=51.02020032242967 HTTP/1.1" 200 87 362 362
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Aug/2014:18:38:43 +0000] "GET /v1/stores?page_number=0&radius=50&lng=145.15730558&items_per_page=20&lat=-38.15366074&eligibility_cc=AU HTTP/1.1" 200 86 345 345
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Aug/2014:18:38:43 +0000] "GET /v1/stores?quality_filter=true&page_number=0&radius=50&lng=-81.21630957375716&items_per_page=100&lat=41.16861975744389 HTTP/1.1" 200 87 363 363
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Aug/2014:18:38:43 +0000] "GET /v1/stores?quality_filter=true&page_number=0&radius=50&lng=-119.1483695757371&items_per_page=100&lat=34.20897662590266 HTTP/1.1" 200 87 246 246
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `COMMONAPACHELOG` since you don't have referer or useragent in your log file.